# QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component: [...] module "QtQuick" is not installed

Tags: ios, qt, qt-creator, qtquick2

I'm facing problems with Qt deployment for iOS.
My project is using QtQuick without problems on different plattforms (e.g Android, Mac ...). But when it comes to launch the same code in iOS Simulator it fails with a black simulator screen and the message:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qml/WmsWindow.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
qrc:/qml/WmsWindow.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/qml/WmsWindow.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/qml/WmsWindow.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
qrc:/qml/WmsWindow.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/qml/WmsWindow.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/qml/WmsWindow.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
qrc:/qml/WmsWindow.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/qml/WmsWindow.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
```

I'm using this command for import in the qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
```

"quick" is added in the .pro file. The App is opened this way:

```
m_pEngine = new QQmlApplicationEngine(this);
m_pEngine->load(p_qFilename);
```

Like said before, the same project is successfully launching on other platforms. I don't know why this problem is occurring on iOS.(Compilation works without problems, also on iOS). The Qt examples are starting without problems but I can't find any differences in declarations.
The only difference to qt examples is I'm using a lot of own developed libraries, which are linked to the executable. Has anyone seen this kind of problem before? Do you have an idea how to get this fixed?

Comment: It's hard to say. You can selectively remove you libs and check if some has a (quite strange) interaction with the frameworks. Also, Qt Creator generates a XCode project for you once compilation is done: maybe you can try to debug that.